# CSS overlay avoid overlap scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an horizontal scroll indicator overlay to let know the user that there is more content scrolling. The problem is that the overlay is overlaping the scrollbar's div.

This is the example code I am using https://codepen.io/jonathantejedera/pen/ExpbEmP.

The code:

```css
.containerwrapper {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: calibri;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.containerwrapper:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, red);
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 17px);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerwrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div>item1 - test</div>
    <div>item2 - test</div>
    <div>item3 - test</div>
    <div>item4 - test</div>
    <div>item5 - test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I set the brackground to red, and behind the color there is the scrollbar I want to keep.
How can I show the background and keep the scrollbar visible?

Thanks you.

Comment: Why use a pseudo element for the background? why not just put it on the container wrapper or container? but if you are set on using a pseudo element, then make it's z-index -1 instead of 0, it will push it behind the scroll bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it change the `z-index: 0;` to `z-index:-1`;

```css
.containerwrapper {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: calibri;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.containerwrapper:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, red);
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 17px);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: -1;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerwrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div>item1 - test</div>
    <div>item2 - test</div>
    <div>item3 - test</div>
    <div>item4 - test</div>
    <div>item5 - test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```